# How to set drop down item as selected using jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, thymeleaf

I'm hoping someone can help with an issue I'm having. I'm working on a form which is being used on a web app we're developing.  I've created a title field that when "other" is clicked - it will display another drop down menu (with other titles).  My issue is once the form is saved, and we go back to edit the form, if "other" has been selected - it will not show the selected other title.

For example you are a Sir - we save the form - go back to the form to edit customer details - it will not show the selected title but if we save the form again - it still shows as Sir - so it is selecting it from the page, just not showing it visibly.

here is the snippet:

```js
function titlehandler(objName)
{

var titlefield = objName.value;
document.patientDetailsForm.hiddentitle.value = titlefield;
extratitleupdate();
}

function extratitleupdate()
{

var titlevalue = document.patientDetailsForm.hiddentitle.value;
if (titlevalue == "Other")
{
    document.getElementById("othertitle").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("othertitle").hidden = false;
    document.getElementById("other-label").style.display = 'none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("othertitle").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("othertitle").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("other-label").style.display = '';
}
}
```

```html
<form name="patientDetailsForm">

<fieldset  class="title-box">

<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemr" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemr" id="mr-label">Mr</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemrs" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemrs" id="mrs-label">Mrs</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemiss" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemiss" id="miss-label">Miss</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlems" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlems" id="ms-label">Ms</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Other" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titleother" th:field="*{title}" /><label for="titleother" id="other-label">Other</label>
<select name="name" class="multidrop" id="othertitle" disabled="" hidden="" th:field="*{title}"><option value="Dr">Dr</option>
<option value="Rev">Rev</option>
<option value="Sir">Sir</option>
<option value="Sist">Sist</option></select>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddentitle" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="valid" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{personId}" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please provide whole form and script you used to save the dropdown value?
That will help to resolve

Comment: Hi, the form uses Java Springboot/Thymeleaf - I'd have to upload the whole project.  Ideally i'd like to know if what I'm asking is doable with JS/jQuery or would we need to look at developing something in Java?

Comment: You can do it in either in  JS/Jquery or in java as well.
One idea is to save the selected value in `session` and set the value on reload.

Comment: did you try $("#other-label").val("Sir") in if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById("othertitle").selectedIndex = "0";` to select first element of **dropdown**.

if you want to use **jQuery** , you can do something like :

```
$("#othertitle").val("Sir");
```

Here is working example :

```js
function titlehandler(objName)
{

var titlefield = objName.value;
document.patientDetailsForm.hiddentitle.value = titlefield;
extratitleupdate();
}

function extratitleupdate()
{

var titlevalue = document.patientDetailsForm.hiddentitle.value;
if (titlevalue == "Other")
{
    document.getElementById("othertitle").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("othertitle").hidden = false;
    document.getElementById("other-label").style.display = 'none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("othertitle").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("othertitle").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("other-label").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("othertitle").selectedIndex = "0";

}
}
```

```html
<form name="patientDetailsForm">

<fieldset  class="title-box">

<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemr" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemr" id="mr-label">Mr</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemrs" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemrs" id="mrs-label">Mrs</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemiss" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemiss" id="miss-label">Miss</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlems" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlems" id="ms-label">Ms</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Other" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titleother" th:field="*{title}" /><label for="titleother" id="other-label">Other</label>
<select name="name" class="multidrop" id="othertitle" disabled="" hidden="" th:field="*{title}"><option value="Dr">Dr</option>
<option value="Rev">Rev</option>
<option value="Sir">Sir</option>
<option value="Sist">Sist</option></select>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddentitle" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="valid" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{personId}" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.  The code you have given will select the first element of the drop down.  What I need is to mark whichever title the user selects to selected.  If that makes sense - not mark the first dropdown as selected.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @sconner87, When you edit , how will you get information? are you using ajax call to get user information?